# Como somar os valores numéricos dentro de um String em C?

Tags: c, string

Bom dia, preciso escrever um código que receba um número e retorne a soma dos dígitos desse número.
 Por exemplo, caso o usuário digite *123456789* o programa deve imprimir *45 (1+2+3+4...)*. 
 Acho que o jeito mais fácil seria armazenar o número em uma string e então somar os elementos em cada posição da string, porém não sei como fazer para somar os elementos da string. 
 Alguns sites sugerem usar a função `atoi()` porém ela recebe o valor da string inteira e não de um elemento especifico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `atoi` serve para converter uma string inteira para numero e não cada caractere. Para converter um caractere para número basta utilizar a [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) e fazer uma subtração.

Se tiver o caractere `'2'` e quiser ficar com o numero `2` pode subtrair o valor do caractere `'0'` que lhe vai dar `2`

Exemplo:

- `'2'` => letra 50 da tabela ascii
- `'0'` => letra 48 da tabela ascii

`'2'-'0' = 50 - 48 = 2` que era o valor que se queria.

Para utilizar isso no seu código pode fazer a lógica mesmo sem utilizar a biblioteca de string e utilizando ponteiros, assim:

```
char numero[] = "123456789";

char *letra = numero; //ponteiro letra aponta para o primeiro caractere
int soma = 0;

while (*letra!='\0'){ //enquanto não apanhar o terminador da string
    soma += (*letra) - '0'; //conversão de letra para número e soma
    letra++; //aponta para a proxima letra
}

printf("%s dá como soma de numeros %d", numeros,soma);
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Ik3mYP)

Answer (score 1):

Em *C#* você pode usar o [Convert.ToInt16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0046aasy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string digitos = "123456";
string retorno = string.Empty;
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < digitos.Length; i++){
   total += Convert.ToInt16(digitos[i]);

   if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(retorno))
      retorno += " +";
   retorno += digitos[i];
}
retorno = total + " (" + retorno + ")";
Console.WriteLine(retorno);
```

---

Em *C*, pelo que me lembro, pode fazer a conversão assim; acredito que os *printfs* montem o retorno esperado:

```
char digitos[6] = "123456";
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < digitos.Length; i++){
   total += (digitos[i] - '0');
}
printf("%s (", total);
for(int i = 0; i < digitos.Length; i++){
   if (i == 0)
      printf("%c ", digitos[i]);
   else
      printf("+ %c", digitos[i]);
}
printf(")",);
```

Comment: Em C vetores não tem propriedades. Então o `digitos.Length` deveria ser substituído diretamente pelo 6. Ou, nesse caso, há a opção de usar o operador `sizeof` para derivar o tamanho do vetor (mas só porque a declaração está no próprio bloco do cálculo do tamanho; se tivesse em uma passagem de parâmetro, não garanto que o `sizeof` funcione corretamente)

Comment: Outra coisa, no primeiro `printf`: `printf("%d (", total);`. Com o `%s` o `printf` vai interpretar o argumento como um ponteiro de `char` nulo terminado, o que possivelmente não é o desejado

Answer (score 0):

Que tal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digsum( const char * s )
{
    int i = 0;
    int soma = 0;

    while( s[i] )
        soma += ( s[i++] - '0' );

    return soma;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", digsum("123456789") );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o ponto negativo. Quem negativou poderia explicar?